# 404 error when trying to send records to a database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to do a crud with php with the pdo method (I am just learning this method), also combining it with a sweetalert to give it a better appearance, I have an error that when giving a send button, I get the following error in console

```
POSThttp://localhost/proyectos/php/registrarse.php
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 4ms]
```

These are the files involved in the process. Could you help me to solve this error? Thanks in advance.

code register php

```
<?php

     require_once "../procesos/crud.php";
     $datos=array(
          'identificaion' => $_POST['nitr'],
          'nombre' => $_POST['nombre'],
          'apellido' => $_POST['apellido'],
          'correo' => $_POST['correo'],
          'clave' => $_POST['clave'],
          'direccion' => $_POST['direccion'],
          'numero' => $_POST['telefono'],
          'genero' => $_POST['genero'],
          //'confirmacion clave' => $_POST['clave2']
     );
     echo Crud::insertarDatos($datos);
?>
```

crud code, which is like the intermediary between the different files

```
<?php
     require_once "../php/Conexion.php";
      class Crud extends Conexion{
          public function insertarDatos($datos){
               $Registrar="INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`IDENTIFICACION`, `PRIMER_NOMBRE`,`PRIMER_APELLIDO`,`CORRE`, `CLAVE`, `DIRECCION`, `TELEFONO`, `ID_TIPO_USUARIO_FK`, `ID_GENERO_FK`) VALUES (':nit',':nombre', ':apellido', ':correo', ':clave', ':direccion', ':telefono', ':tipo_usuario', ':genero');";
               $queryRegistrar=Conexion::conectar()->prepare($Registrar);
               $queryRegistrar->bindParam(":nit",$datos["nitr"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $queryRegistrar->bindParam(":nombre",$datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $queryRegistrar->bindParam(":apellido",$datos["apellido"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $queryRegistrar->bindParam(":correo",$datos["correo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $queryRegistrar->bindParam(":clave",$datos["clave"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $queryRegistrar->bindParam(":direccion",$datos["direccion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $queryRegistrar->bindParam(":telefono",$datos["telefono"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $queryRegistrar->bindParam(":genero",$datos["genero"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
               return $queryRegistrar->execute();
               $queryRegistrar->Close();
          }
          
     }
     

?>
```

I code processes.js which is responsible for displaying the sweetalert with ajax

```
function insertarDatos() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../php/registrarse.php",
    data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
    success:function (r) {
      console.log("adsdadaas");
      if (r == 1) {
        $("#formulario")[0].reset();
        swal("exito", ":D", "success");
      } else {
        swal("error", ":(", "error");
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be wrong but it looks like you are posting to an incorrect URL

```
POST http://localhost/proyectos/php/registrarse.php
```

But your example code same

```
register.php
```

So does your ajax reject need to post to `registrarse.php` or `register.php`?